# Jdbc Driver Not Found

Tags: mysql, exception, netbeans, jdbc, driver

We are working on a project in netbeans using Java which uses mysql database to process some common queries. But I am having issues with loading jdbc drivers for mysql in netbeans. It is giving following error:

Class Not Found Exception : com.jdbc.mysql.Driver 
 please help me out.

Comment: Is the jar added to your classpath?

Comment: how to add the jar file to classpath

Comment: Found this site- http://www.seo4fun.com/blog/2007/06/16/jdbc-classnotfoundexception-netbeans-classpath-java.html. Watch out for the netbeans section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to add the MySQL JDBC connector to your project. It would be similar for an Oracle database, for example (you would have to add the ojdbc6.jar).

For MySQL, you have to get the MySQL JDBC connector and add it to your project's classpath.

- Get the MySQL JDBC connector, either on the MySQL site, either adding it through a Maven dependency (if your project is driven by Maven), check [the official MySQL site](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). The current version as of May 2012 is 5.1.19 (works with any version of MySQL);
- Add it to your Netbeans classpath, in the project properties. Check the [online Netbeans configuration about project classpath if needed](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath)

Answer (score 2):

When your suffering from  this kind of problem then you need to check MySQL version is updated or corrected . If your are working on normal program then add MySQL jar version 5.1.32 or if you used maven structure then you used this dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.32</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope that it will work on your problem.....

Answer (score 0):

if we add any jar files related  data base drivers to class path are not visible in the IDE.
so once again we must  add jar file to IDE in library folder,then only the classes in jar file can identified,in the IDE.